# How to do audit on Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

How to do audit on Hyperledger Fabric?

In the link of below:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/ffbf21a5b781b938f4168def6541f6fbae792d31/docs/biz/usecases.md
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/cca26e6d9aa9e6fab2b5c17d311709130b52c46e/docs/protocol-spec.md

There are audit introductions, so how to do audit setting/configuration, coding , etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if audit features are implemented yet.

According to https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/wiki/Fabric-Next (roadmap?)

```
Auditability: Provide auditing APIs
```

Comment: It might be good for December this year, according to this roadmap: http://lists.hyperledger.org/pipermail/hyperledger-fabric/attachments/20160803/26504609/attachment-0001.pdf#13